# Converting all input fields to button using Paperclip Gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am working on my first Rails project and have installed the [Paperclip Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip/versions/4.3.6) to handle image uploads.  As is, it works fine, but all the upload fields are displayed to be fill out separately as seen in the screen shot below.

[image]

Below is my code as is with all the image input fields broken out individually.

**models/project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: '680x300>', thumb: '170x75>' }, default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png"'
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: '/\Aimage\/.*\z/'
end
```

**admin/project.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  permit_params :name, :content, :price, :image

  show do |t|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :content
      row :price
      row :image do
        project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, 'No Photo Yet')
      end
    end
  end

  # form html: { enctype: 'multipart/form-data' } do |f|
  #   f.input do
  #     f.input :name
  #     f.input :content
  #     f.input :price
  #     f.input :image, hint: f.project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, 'Upload JPG/PNG/GIF Image')
  #   end
  #   f.actions
  # end
end
```

I know that there is a way to take all these inputs and have them automatic as part of an upload button, but am having a hard time with the code; I keep getting the error below when I uncomment the other part of my `admin/project.rb` code.

I am using ActiveAdmin, Paperclip 5.1 and Rails 5.1.1

```
Started GET "/admin/projects/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-26 13:14:33 -0700
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  AdminUser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering /Users/rooster/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb
  CACHE Project Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered /Users/rooster/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb (129.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 163ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)
```

Comment: Are there any other errors in the log prior to the `ActionView::Template::Error` ?

Comment: @jdgray I added what was displayed in the console to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple changes that would have to be made with your form.

It currently looks like:

```
form html: { enctype: 'multipart/form-data' } do |f|
  f.input do
    f.input :name
    f.input :content
    f.input :price
    f.input :image, hint: f.project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, 'Upload JPG/PNG/GIF Image')
  end
  f.actions
end
```

And it should look something like:

```
form html: { enctype: 'multipart/form-data' } do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :name
    f.input :content
    f.input :price
    f.input :image, hint: resource.project.image? ? image_tag(project.image.url, height: '100') : content_tag(:span, 'Upload JPG/PNG/GIF Image')
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Two minor changes that were made. Changed `input` to `inputs`, got this from after looking at ActiveAdmin's documentation about [forms](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html). Next I changed `f.project.image?` to `resource.project.image?`. `resource` corresponds with your `Project` object.